# how to check if an object prop has the required object properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am passing an object to my component as:

```
<foo :ob='object'></foo>
```

And inside my component, I have this declaration:

```
props: {
  ob: {
    type: Object,
    required: false, 
    default: {}
  }
}
```

Usually, the expected object to pass is something like this:

```
{

  bar: [],
  tar: {
    a: false,
  }
}
```

Now, how do I make sure in props that the object passed is similar. I don't need to check the values, I just need to know it contains the object keys  ,bar, tar and on property inside tar, which is: a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [custom validator](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

```js
props: {
  ob: {
    type: Object,
    required: false, 
    validator: function (obj) {
      return 'bar' in obj &&
      'tar' in obj &&
      obj.tar instanceof Object &&
      'a' in obj.tar
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but what if the object  is not what I expected, do I throw an error or revert back to some state?

Comment: The docs states that Vue will produce a console warning. So I guess validations is not strict from the framework's prespective.